# Difference between "had been ...-ing" and "was/were ...-ing"?

Tags: tenses

I couldn't understand the difference between these sentences:

> َ1.We were watching TV when he arrived.
>
> 2.We had been watching TV when he arrived.

OR

> 1.I was listening music when you called.
>
> 2.I had been listening music when
> you called.

Comment: In this context, 'had been' suggests that the activity had finished when the visitor arrived.

Comment: The second pair isn't grammatical unless you consider yourself to actually *be* a type of music.

Comment: @Lawrence: May you explain more?

Comment: "Listening music" is a noun phrase, like "loud music" or "calm water" or "bright light". Possibly called a bare role noun phrase, like the bare role noun "king" in "I am king". It describes something of the 'essence' of the subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Had been' refers to an unspecified period in the past: Egyptians had been making papyrus for centuries.

'Was/were' indicates the recent past: That papyrus was intact as of an hour ago.